# Visudo not working for specified files

Tags: sudo, visudo

I am trying to give sudo ability without the need of passwords to specific files. So far I have:

employee ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/file_name

The file has a simple chmod command, in the bash script it has at the very bottom "sudo chmod ..." and it will prompt me for the password.

I have tried it as:

employee ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

this will cause it to work, but I only want it to NOT ask for the password for this single file.

Eventually I want to also configure it to use root's password for sudo (I know it's not the most secure thing to do, and is not recommended). I know at that point you will need to enter in Defaults rootpw.

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I'm sure it's something silly.

Comment: You can configure `sudo` for commands to run with elevated privileges, not files...

Comment: What would be the best way to do what I mentioned then?

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the

```
sudo chmod ...
```

command at the bottom of `/home/file_name`. Instead just put

```
chmod ...
```

And execute `/home/file_name` as sudo:

```
sudo /home/file_name
```

Do make sure that only `root` has write privileges for that file, or you're giving away the keys to the castle.

Comment: The file needs to be executable by multiple users that should not have sudo access. The goal is to still give them the chmod ability which lets them change the permissions of files that they may or may not own.

Comment: @JamesBoind Yes. Just make the script in `file_name` do what it should do (such as checking that the user is allowed to `chmod` some specific file), make it root-writable and world-executable, and add a NOPASSWD rule for it to the `sudoers` file. Make sure that the file itself is exempt from being `chmodded` by any user. Also, if you have untrusted users, prepare for havoc.